# Ajax validation for Go programs

Tags: go

Is there a Go package that supports data validation for restful apis?

It would be good if there were something similar to active model validation in Ruby?

I tried various ways but couldn't find something that offers good abstration of this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[go-validator](https://github.com/go-validator/validator) has support for tags and custom validators on top of the built-in ones. It can easily be added to the models for your API resources.